# How can I make a platform wait a few seconds before spinning again in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm currently making a 2D game as a beginner. I already added a spinning platform to unity. Now I want the platform to wait a certain amount of seconds, when the platform is straight, before it's turning around again, like on the gif. So that you can choose the number of seconds easily on the right side of unity. Can someone explain me pls?

Thanks

GIF: [NeonBeats Platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFp1W.gif)

Current Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spinning_Platform : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float rotZ;
    public float RotationSpeed;
    public bool ClockwiseRotation;

    void Update()
    {
        if (ClockwiseRotation==false)
        {
            rotZ += Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            rotZ += -Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotZ);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the condition for the time and also the rotation.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spinning_Platform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotZ;
    public float RotationSpeed;
    public bool ClockwiseRotation;
    public float time = 1;

    void Update()
    {
        time -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (time <= 0)
        {
            rotZ += 10;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotZ);
            if (rotZ == 180)
            {
                rotZ = 0;
                time = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't working. It says a namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Comment: The spinning works now, but the textures are somehow wrong. The platform texture is still upside down when it turned one time. The rotation speed and the clockwise rotation aren't working properly as well.

Comment: Can you give more details about what are you trying to achieve? that rotation is same as the GIF.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but the problem is that the two variables RotationSpeed and ClockwiseRotation aren't working anymore with this script. And as I said the texture is somehow wrong, maybe you know, what it could be.